# amusement park scheduling rides using dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, analysis

> You arrive at Waldo's World Amusement Park with T minutes remaining until the park closes. The park has n rides and your objective is to complete as many rides as possible before the park closes. (For this problem, taking the same ride twice counts as 2 rides.) You are given a table W such that W(i, t) gives you the waiting time for ride i at time t. For convenience, assume that t is expressed as minutes before the park closes. Ride i itself takes ri minutes and all times are measured in integer minutes.

I tried solving it using a method similar to 0 1 knapsack problem. But the Table W which contains the waiting time for ride i varies wrt to time t. Is it exactly a knapsack plus activity selection combined problem?

Comment: Show us what you tried, with code, and someone may point you in the right direction

Comment: The recursion function that I have written is  as follows: given n rides , If ride i is chosen, I call the next recursion passing the parameters which are ride i+1 and total time - time taken by ride i. If ride i is not chosen the parameters passed are ride i+1 and the time T

Comment: If for all t and i, W(i, t+1) - W(i, t) >= -1 then it is quite simple. In other words if you wait x minutes the waiting time cannot drop more than x minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Would this make any sense? Let `f(t)` represent the most achievable rides at time `t`. Then:

```
// Higher t is back in time
// since t is how many minutes
// before the park closes

f(t) = max(
  // Not taking any ride
  f(t - 1),

  // Take ride i
  1 + f(t - W(i, t) - r_i)
)
for all i
```

Comment: Provided you have a termination condition, yes :-)